BigInteger addition and subtraction implementation c#
I have an assignment to implement BigInteger. I have this code, which works correctly, when we have 2 possitive integers. Inside each method, the usual algorithm for adding or subtracting in a column is to operate on each bit of the number (that are in the array) in turn, with the bits being carried over as needed. In constructor i convert string representation to inner int array IN REVERSED ORDER for example, "123434" is converted to _numbers = {4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}
    public BigInteger Add(BigInteger another)
    {
        var transposition = 0;
        var i = 0;

        var maxDischarge = Math.Max(_numbers.Length, another._numbers.Length);

        var res = new int[maxDischarge + 1];
        
        while (i < maxDischarge || transposition != 0)
        {

            var sum = transposition;
            
            if (i < _numbers.Length)
            {
                sum += _numbers[i];
            }

            if (i < another._numbers.Length)
            {
                sum += another._numbers[i];
            }

            res[i] = sum % 10;      
            transposition = sum / 10;

            i++;
        }
        
        return new BigInteger(res, _isNeg);
    }

    public BigInteger Sub(BigInteger another)
    {
        var transition = 0;
        var i = 0;
        
        var maxDischarge = Math.Max(_numbers.Length, another._numbers.Length);

        var res = new int[maxDischarge];

        while (i < _numbers.Length || i < another._numbers.Length)
        {
            var sub = -transition;

            if (_numbers.Length > another._numbers.Length)
            {
                if (i < _numbers.Length)
                {
                    sub += _numbers[i];
                }
                
                if (i < another._numbers.Length)
                {
                    sub -= another._numbers[i];
                }
                
                if (sub < 0)
                {
                    sub += 10;
                    transition = 1;
                }
                else                        // by chat gpt
                {
                    transition = 0;
                }
                             
                res[i] = sub;
                i++;
            }
            else if (_numbers.Length < another._numbers.Length)
            {
                if (i < another._numbers.Length)
                {
                    sub += another._numbers[i];
                }

                if (i < _numbers.Length)
                {
                    sub -= _numbers[i];
                }
                
                if (sub < 0)
                {
                    sub += 10;
                    transition = 1;
                }
                else                        // by chat gpt
                {
                    transition = 0;
                }
                             
                res[i] = sub;
                i++;
            }
            
        }

        return new BigInteger(res, _isNeg);
    }
}

But I have a problem how to implement addition and subtraction with negative numbers
I have added a bool private readonly bool _isNeg; and in method ToString I check if number _isNeg


Adding two negative integers results in a negative integer, and adding their absolute values. 2. Adding a positive integer to a negative integer is equivalent to subtracting the absolute value of the negative integer from the positive integer.

